# 36 Bits Stored in DWORD? (x86 assembly MASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

```
.data
source DWORD 20 DUP(0FFFFFFFFh)
target DWORD 20 DUP(?)
.code
...
```

The above code is taken from Kip Irvine's latest 7th edition on page 355. Apparently, 20x36 bits are stored into 32?

Comment: Well, of course not.  You have to prefix "0" on hexadecimal number that start with a letter.  If you don't then the assembler thinks it is a symbol instead of a number.  Like 0DEADBEEFh is a number, DEADBEEFh is a symbol.

Answer (score 5):

0FFFFFFFFh is 32 bits.  You add the leading zero on some compilers, but it's still 32 bits.

0Fh = 1111 in binary,4 bits.

00000000Fh is still 1111 in binary.

The DUP 20 just says duplicate that DWORD 20 times, so source is allocate to 20 DWORDs of 0FFFFFFFFh and target is just allocated to 20 DWORDs of uninitialised values. I presume the code will go on to copy the data from source to target.